# Finding the source of a ulimit setting

Tags: linux, centos, ulimit, limits

On my CentOS 6.2 server the value of `ulimit -v` (virtual memory) is `1048576`. However, this is not set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (which is empty) or `.../limit.d/` (which contains only a max processes setting).

How can I find the source of this value? Is it the default, maybe? (Doesn't appear to be so, since on an unrelated CentOS server I know it's `unlimited`)

Answer (score 1):

The default is `unlimited`. It is possible to **lower** ulimits values as an unprivileged account though, so you might want to take a look in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d` and / or your personal shell configuration files.